# CSS / JQuery: Setting href as background image

Tags: jquery, css

Background images have some enviable CSS properties that I'd like to use for photo galleries -- namely, `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center center;` let you use an image of any aspect ratio and fit it attractively to a fixed-size container.

However, I don't really think setting background images with content is ideal. I'd much rather have `<a href="url.jpg"><img src="url.jpg"/></a>` in content than `<a href="url.jpg" style="background-image: url(url.jpg);"><img src="url.jpg"/></a>`. I think a script to take the former and write the latter is ideal.

Given code that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-23.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-24.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-26.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-27.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-28.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-29.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-30.jpg"></a>
```

I'm trying to write a JQuery script to take the href URL and set it as the background image. Basically, turning the above code into this:

```
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-23.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-23.jpg);"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-24.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-24.jpg);"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-26.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-26.jpg);"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-27.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-27.jpg);"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-28.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-28.jpg);"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-29.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-29.jpg);"></a>
<a href="http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-30.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://thesundaybe.st/media/from-earth-phone-30.jpg);"></a>
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the basic HTML/CSS set up, just needing a bit of JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/tv3q8/3/

And theoretically, this is what it'd look like when the script does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/tv3q8/

I got fairly close this this bit of JQuery, but it seems to just use the first href as the background image for all of the `<a>` tags.

```
$('a').css({'background-image': 'url(' + $('a').attr('href') + ')'});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('a').css('background-image', function() {
    return 'url(' + this.href + ')';
});
```

`each` loop will be used internally so it's equivalent to `$('a').each` + `$(this).css` combination.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tv3q8/11/)

Comment: @PSCoder Yes, a lot of jQuery methods accept function + we can skip redundant `each` very often. Makes code a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('href') + ')'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/tv3q8/8/

Comment: This also seems to yield the same problem I've been running into. The first href URL gets set as the background image for all of the `<a>` tags, rather than the unique href included in each `<a>` tag.

Comment: see change in this line  `$(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('href') + ')'});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').each(function(){    
 $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + this.href + ')'});
});
```

Here `this` refers to the current element in iteration.

http://jsfiddle.net/x5kbA/

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I was trying earlier and seems to yield the same problem -- the first href URL gets set as the background image for all `<a>` tags. See: http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/tv3q8/9/